Finite difference method for a product of functions
Consider the following partial derivative: partial (x*f(x)*g(x)) / partial x
When using the finite difference method (FD) for partial differential equations is it more accurate to apply the partial derivative product rule to the term in parenthesis then use the FD method for each derivative term in the result f(x)g(x) + xgdf/dx + xfdg/dx or to label it say A = x*f(x)g(x) then use the FD method on partial A / partial x in which case we would use say (A[i+1,j] - A[i-1,j])/2dx? Is there a way to prove mathematically perhaps via a Taylor series that one is more accurate than the other? Any help with this is greatly appreciated.
I wanted to try to mathematically prove one is more accurate than the other say via a Taylor series but was not sure where to begin.
